# CSV not correct format on s3 bucket not giving the data correctly displayed

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

```
const fs = require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: 'key',
  secretAccessKey: 'accesskey'
});

const fileName = 'atest.csv';

const uploadFile = () => {
  fs.readFile(fileName, (err, data) => {
     if (err) throw err;
     const params = {
         Bucket: 'mybucket1s-resized', // pass your bucket name
         Key: 'FlightReporttest.csv', // file will be saved as testBucket/contacts.csv
         ContentDisposition: 'attachment',
         Body: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
     };
     s3.upload(params, function(s3Err, data) {
         if (s3Err) throw s3Err
         console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`)
     });
  });
};

uploadFile();
```

> It uploads to the bucket fine but when I download that csv I get a
>   different format `` [csv format when downloaded from s3][1]   [1]:
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF46l.png
>   any suggestions? if I change the body to anything else it throws an error
>
> ```
>          Body: stream
>                ^
> ```

ReferenceError: stream is not defined
    at fs.readFile (C:\Users\cloudone\Desktop\Work\Projects info\Pageman_Flight_Reports\flightreportupload\index.js:17:16)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't want to `JSON.stringify()` a CSV file on upload. If you were to remove that from your code it would upload correctly, just pass `data`

I've also tidied up the code a little below

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const fs = require('fs')

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: 'key',
    secretAccessKey: 'accesskey',
})

const uploadFile = fileName => {
    const params = {
        Bucket: 'mybucket1s-resized',
        Key: 'FlightReporttest.csv',
        ContentDisposition: 'attachment',
        Body: fs.readFileSync(fileName),
    }

    return s3.upload(params).promise()
}

uploadFile('atest.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks so much @razki, sorry I am new to this so still learning